# Raspberry Pi Wireless USB stick

Tags: drivers, usb, wifi, raspberry-pi

I recently acquired a Raspberry Pi, and have installed Debian Squeeze on it, and after doing a small bit of research (I'm not too proficient with Linux) I found and ordered a USB wireless dongle ("LevelOne WUA-0605 N_Max Wireless USB Adapter") that appears to have support for Linux.

[This is the page](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RT2800USB.html) I found that looks like it says the dongle has a Linux driver. I installed (what I think) was the driver package, `firmware-ralink`. Now I'm not sure what i need to do to make it work.  `lsusb` lists the device as

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
    RTL8191SU 802.11n wLAN Adapter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem may be that the Raspberry-Pi uses an arm cpu whereas most linux computers use intel/amd.

[Here](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Working_USB_Wifi_Adapters)
on the Raspberry-Pi wiki there is a list of tested usb wifi dongles. If you cannot get yours to work or cannot get the correct driver then you may consider buying one of these.

If you have a model b and can connect your pi to the internet try `sudo apt-get install firmware-ralink` If you cannot get it to work then the pi forums would be a better place to ask for help because they will give you more specialized answers.

Good Luck.

Comment: in most post i said that i have already tried installing `firmware-ralink`

Comment: I know you did, I just suggested trying another method. You can probably get your dongle to work, just make sure that you take into account the fact that the Pi uses ARM.